# How to set different object view by 'logged in' user?

Tags: open62541

Let's say I have two users - UserA & UserB. When UserA connect to my OPC-UA Server based on open62541 I want him to see:

```
Data
    - MyData1
    - MyData2
    - MyData3
```

When UserB connect I want him to see:

```
Data
    - MyData1
```

Is it possible? and if so where do I use it when I set an object node

```
UA_Server_addObjectNode(UA_Server *server, 
                    const UA_NodeId requestedNewNodeId,
                    const UA_NodeId parentNodeId,
                    const UA_NodeId referenceTypeId,
                    const UA_QualifiedName browseName,
                    const UA_NodeId typeDefinition,
                    const UA_ObjectAttributes attr,
                    void *nodeContext, 
                    UA_NodeId *outNewNodeId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that directly via the `UA_Server_addObjectNode`.

The concept you are looking for in OPC UA is called Views.

From the OPC UA Specification, Part 3:

> **View NodeClass**
>
> Underlying systems are often large and Clients often
>   have an interest in only a specific subset of the data. They do not
>   need, or want, to be burdened with viewing Nodes in the AddressSpace
>   for which they have no interest.
>
> To address this problem, this
>   standard defines the concept of a View. Each View defines a subset of
>   the Nodes in the AddressSpace. The entire AddressSpace is the default
>   View. Each Node in a View may contain only a subset of its References,
>   as defined by the creator of the View. The View Node acts as the root
>   for the Nodes in the View. Views are defined using the View NodeClass,
>   which is specified in Table 5.
>
> All Nodes contained in a View shall be
>   accessible starting from the View Node when browsing in the context of
>   the View. It is not expected that all containing Nodes can be browsed
>   directly from the View Node but rather browsed from other Nodes
>   contained in the View.
>
> A View Node may not only be used as additional
>   entry point into the AddressSpace but as a construct to organize the
>   AddressSpace and thus as the only entry point into a subset of the
>   AddressSpace. Therefore Clients shall not ignore View Nodes when
>   exposing the AddressSpace. Simple Clients that do not deal with Views
>   for filtering purposes can, for example, handle a View Node like an
>   Object of type FolderType (see 5.5.3)

So what you need to do is create a View Node, and attach the corresponding nodes to this View Node. The user can then start browsing from that specific view.

The corresponding method is called `UA_Server_addViewNode`. Then use the `UA_Server_addReference` method to reference other nodes within your created view node. The reference type should be `Organizes`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Do you now where I connect a view to specific user?

Comment: You basically create a separate view for all you user types. And your client should then start browsing with a specific view node instead of the root node.